# acces elements of array within array and combine them in one array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have an array which contain following data

```
Array
(
    [ref_no] => 
    [supply_from] => 
    [issue_to] => 
    [issue_date] => 
    [product_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc-20
            [1] => xyz-20
        )

    [purpose_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 100
        )
)
```

i want an array like this using foreach loop to save records in table of database

```
Array(
    'product_id'=>abc-20,
    'purpose_id'=>100
)
```

i have tried this

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$val)
        {

            $result = array(
            'product_id' => $product_id[$key],
            'purpose_id' => $purpose_id[$key]
            );
            print_r($result);
        }
```

Comment: And until now you have tried.... ? Because i also want to see your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$final_array = array();
foreach ($array['product_id'] as $key => $value) {
  $final_array[$key]['product_id']=$value;
  $final_array[$key]['purpose_id']=isset($array['purpose_id'][$key]) ? $array['purpose_id'][$key] : "";
}
print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/892361  OR  https://eval.in/892407 ($_POST variable)

Comment: what if array is coming in $_POST? instead of $array['product_id'] i have to use $_POST as $key=>$value?

Comment: @dan  yes you have to. I just gave an example. But you need to use `$_POST['product_id'] as $key=>$value`.

Comment: this only gives me values for product id, purpose_id is empty

Comment: @dan  where? in my example its fine. It seems that $_POST array structure is different what you posted in your question. Please post the corect structure

Answer (score 1):

Iterare by product_id array and create array which contain product_id and purpose_id. Try below code:

```
<?php
$product_ids = $array['product_id'];
$purpose_ids = $array['purpose_id'];
$new_array = array();
foreach ($product_ids as $key => $value) {
  $tmp_array = array();
  $tmp_array['product_id']=$value;
  $tmp_array['purpose_id']=isset($purpose_ids[$key]) ? $purpose_ids[$key] : "";
  $new_array[] = $tmp_array;

}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access columnar data, so you only need iterate the `product_id` row and use the indexes to access the columns.

Your task can be more simply completed with the following snippet.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/K770f))

```
$_POST=[
    'ref_no'=>'',
    'supply_from'=>'',
    'issue_to'=>'',
    'issue_date'=>'',
    'product_id'=>['abc-20','xyz-20'],
    'purpose_id'=>[100,100]
];

foreach($_POST['product_id'] as $i=>$value){
    $result[]=[$_POST['product_id'][$i],$_POST['purpose_id'][$i]];
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'abc-20',
    1 => 100,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'xyz-20',
    1 => 100,
  ),
)
```